# Calculate a number from two variables

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to complete a mathematical operation with two variables like this :

```
$cv_moteur = $request->input('cv_moteur');
        $distance = $request->input('nm_distance');

        if($cv_moteur === '7CV'){

            $taux = '0,401';
            $rencontre_officiel->taux = $taux;
            $rencontre_officiel->mt_indemnite_km = $taux * $distance;
```

> but when i debug i get $rencontre_officiel->mt_indemnite_km = 0

Why ? i should get : 40,1 . Someone know why i get 0 ?

Here is the result of the debug :

```
#attributes: array:10 [▼
    "rencontre_id" => 38
    "licencie_id" => "125"
    "fonction_officiel_id" => "1"
    "bareme_id" => "1"
    "nm_distance" => "100"
    "mt_prime" => "175.00"
    "cv_moteur" => "7CV"
    "taux" => "0,401"
    "mt_indemnite_km" => 0
    "statut_officiel" => ""
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: is it `$taux = '0,401';` or $taux = '0.401'; ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply it's : 0,401

Comment: "0,401" isn't a numeric value; you're going to have difficulty multiplying anything by that...

Comment: Now then, if you were to do `floatval(str_replace(",",".", $taux)) * floatVal($distance)` you might get a result.

Comment: how i could achieve 0,401 * 100 ?

Comment: Well, 0,401 isn't a number (although I know some languages use "," as the decimal point, so I understand where that is coming from). Adding an answer for you.

Comment: Amazing !!!! thanks a lot Tim !!!!!!!!!

Comment: it's working !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `$taux = "0,401";` is treated as a String. Attempting to convert this to a number using a method like `floatval($taux)` will result in `0`, as using "," as a decimal point is invalid in calculations (valid in language though).

What you need to do is convert the `","` to a `"."`:

```
$taux = floatval(str_replace(",",".", $taux));
```

Following that, you should be able to call:

```
$rencontre_officiel->mt_indemnite_km = $taux * floatval($distance);
```